# Printing Caption of an environment in text automatically

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, environments

Consider the following situation

> Suppose that I have several environments, each with a caption. To be clear, suppose that I have the following environments:
>
> > ```
> > \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
> > \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
> > \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
> > ```
>
> Now I've used one of the as follows
>
> > ```
> > \begin{theorem}
> >    My theorem is a world shaking result like P = NP (just for fun :) ).
> >    \begin{itemize}
> >       \item part one
> >       \item part two
> >    \end{itemize}
> > \end{theorem}
> > \begin{proof}
> >  As for the the first part of this theorem, I will do the second...
> > \end{proof}
> > ```

Now, suppose I have changed the type of `theorem` environment to `lemma`, then in the `proof` environment, I want the term `theorem` changes automatically to `lemma`.

Unfortunately, I could not find any specific hack to make this automatic. However, I know it is possible, since I use `cleveref` for referring to labels and it changes accordingly. But how does it do so, I do not know!

A minimal working example is included as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} %[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
       My theorem is a world shaking result like P = NP (just for fun :) ).
       \begin{itemize}
          \item part one
          \item part two
       \end{itemize}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
     As for the the first part of this theorem, I will do the second...
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already using `cleveref`, it provides the command `\namecref`.

Use it as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} %[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}\label{any}
       My theorem is a world shaking result like P = NP (just for fun :) ).
       \begin{itemize}
          \item part one
          \item part two
       \end{itemize}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
     As for the the first part of this \namecref{any}, I will do the second...
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Now, change `theorem` to `lemma` in the example and you will get

[image]

Comment: @AliShakiba You're welcome.